# Find and copy numbered paragraphs into individual cells in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I want to copy numbered paragraphs from Word to Excel.

I want to copy below paragraphs into individual cells in Excel

1. heading
   this is paragraph
2. heading 2
   this is paragraph
3. heading 3
   this is paragraph
4. this is itself a paragraph

I am able to count the number of numbered items via below function but stuck in copy and break till another numbered item.

```vb
count_observations = ActiveDocument.Content.ListFormat.CountNumberedItems(Level:=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I finaly figured it out by researching and searching the other posts. here's the below solution i've come up with.

```
Sub AutoDatabase()

excel_path = "D:/test.xlm"

Dim obs_range1 As Word.Range
Dim obs_range2 As Word.Range
Dim response_range1 As Word.Range
Dim response_range2 As Word.Range


Dim obs As String
Dim response As String
Dim Z As Integer

Set obs_range1 = ActiveDocument.Range
Set obs_range2 = ActiveDocument.Range
Set response_range1 = ActiveDocument.Range
Set response_range2 = ActiveDocument.Range


x = ActiveDocument.Content.ListFormat _
    .CountNumberedItems(Level:=1)


For y = 1 To x
    
    If obs_range1.Find.Execute(FindText:="CopyThis") Then
        Set obs_range2 = ActiveDocument.Range(obs_range1.End, ActiveDocument.Range.End)
        If obs_range2.Find.Execute(FindText:="CopyThis") Then
            obs = ActiveDocument.Range(obs_range1.End, obs_range2.Start).Text
    
    If response_range1.Find.Execute(FindText:="Branch Comments") Then
        Set response_range2 = ActiveDocument.Range(response_range1.End, ActiveDocument.Range.End)
        If response_range2.Find.Execute(FindText:="CopyThis") Then
            response = ActiveDocument.Range(response_range1.End, response_range2.Start).Text
        'MsgBox (response)
    
    With ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows.Add
        With ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(y, 1).Range
        .Text = obs
        End With
        With ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(y, 2).Range
        .Text = response
        End With
    End With
        
        End If
        End If
    End If
    End If
    'MsgBox (obs)
Next y

' Remove ^p from table(1)
With ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Range
    .Find.Execute FindText:="^p", ReplaceWith:="", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
    


End Sub
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).